# concatenate session value with a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following in rails 4

```
<% link = I18n.with_locale(:en){session[:host] && "_faqs_path"} %>
```

will generate a link formed as: `_faqs_path` and not include the session value.  Other forms of concatenation of the session value with the string show up empty while the value exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`<% link = I18n.with_locale(:en){"#{session[:host]}_faqs_path" %>`

Comment: while this generates the string, it gets interpreted to faqs/target_faqs_path, whereas a static string `target_faqs_path` will generate the proper link.  Any idea if this is due to syntax?